# Implementing a secondary authentication scheme in

Tags: database, ldap, oracle10g, oracle-apex

I have an apex application that authenticates using LDAP which would also check to see if a certain value in the database is true or false. I can't see how I can combine authentications.

Comment: Wordpress?  Where does that come in to this?

Comment: Yup...too much programming last night. Sorry for confusion. Apex. Not wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot combine the "pre-configured" schemes provided in APEX.  However you could create a custom authentication scheme that combined LDAP authentication with your other check.  This would need to be manually coded, it could not include the "pre-configured" LDAP functionality.  I don't have any experience of using LDAP authentication so cannot help further.

Comment: Alright, makes sense. I wasn't sure if it was readily available.

Comment: As for AD authentication: the built-in function of apex only does a simple dbms_ldap.simple_bind_s, using the provided inputs. You can very easily write this yourself, a quick google will bring you there.